# How does piggyback script work when same origin policy is enforced in the context of adtech?

Tags: javascript, cookies, web

This [website](http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-exchanges/cookie-syncing/) is a quick explanation on how dsp (demand side platform) does cookie syncing.

According to the website, when user visit a online retail site, if that retail site is in partnership with `DSP1` the DSP can drop a http cookie.

And when the user visit another site with ad inventory, an SSP will try to sync the cookie through the following

`After SSP123 selects a winning bidder though, it runs one last piece of javascript that forces user123 to call out to a handful of regular bidders, including DSP456.`

My question is that how does one `forces user123 to call out` websites that are not in the same origin?

Furthermore how does `SSPcookieXYZ` get pass to DSP if `SSPcookieXYZ` can only be accessed to `SSP123` since its a http only cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer hides in the first part of the sentence:

> you have a **1×1 pixel sitting on your shopping cart page**, which forces the user to call out to DSP456′s web server
>   (emphasis mine)

So, say you are dsp123. Your shopping cart page would then contain the following code:

```
<img src="https://dsp456/spacer.gif" />
```

This creates an HTTP request to DSP456's server and as part of the response there will be a cookie.

The big trick in the second step is the query string.
Assume the following code on SSP123's website:

```
<img src="https://dsp456/spacer.gif?sspCookie=SSPcookieXYZ" />
```

Note that this can as well be:

```
fetch('https://dsp456/track?sspCookie=SSPcookieXYZ')
```

Now remember that we have already set a cookie on `dsp456`, so now `dsp456` has *both* cookies - the information from the sspCookie as well as its own cookie.